# Unzip a package of json files and compare with a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a zip file that contains several json files. How can I unzip it and then compare the titles of those files with a series in pandas to check if there are differences?

For example:

A package contains 2 files:

1. title1.json
2. title2.json

And I have a series: [title1]

So I want to return a series that shows what is in the package but not in the series: [title2]

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to get the list of names of the members of the zip archive

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

my_file = "archive.zip"
with ZipFile(my_file) as my_zip:
    file_names = my_zip.namelist()
```

Then you would just convert the pandas series to a list with the `pd.Series.tolist()` method and compare the two.